# Do selenium tests in django applications increase coverage?

Tags: python, django, selenium, integration-testing, code-coverage

So, do they? That is the question. I'm not seeing any increase in my coverage reports with my integration tests done with selenium.

Comment: If they do, I'd be surprised.  It would be some pretty fancy footwork if code executing requests against a web server were able to deduce what parts of the code on the server it was exercising.

Comment: But this is what I think: When you come across an error in your webapp, django is capable to give you the traceback, even the line of code in which the error came up, so at some point it is aware of what piece of code it's executing at every time!

Comment: Django gives you a stacktrace when it crashes, but it returns it to the client in an HTTP message.  Your app could be written in Cobol as far as Selenium or any other HTTP/TCP/etc-driven framework is concerned.  Besides, once you're talking about something running on the network stack, what about errors coming from outside your code?  Should coverage also track how much of your Apache configuration you are exercising, for instance?

Comment: How to get coverage to measure your selenium tests depends entirely on how you run your Python code during your selenium tests.  If you can run it under coverage.py, then it will be measured.

Answer (score 2):

Well, they increase coverage if they execute code which is not executed by your other tests. However, that won't show up in your reports unless you figure out a way to capture which lines are executed during selenium testing, and add that into the data about coverage.

Comment: I have a LiveServerTestCase that uses a selenium web driver in its tests. When I do './manage.py test' it runs my selenium test, so if I do 'coverage run manage.py test' it should get the covered code by selenium test, right? Should that do the trick?

Comment: @nachoalvarez No. There's no expectation that that "should" work. The coverage measure in most test runners collects data about the code that runs in-process in the test runner. You'll have to do something like run your server through a testcase with coverage counts enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they increase it.

However, you have to script the procedure properly.

My script that runs the relevant tests is the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

coverage run -p ./manage.py test
coverage run -p ./manage.py test path/to/functional/tests
coverage combine
coverage report
# coverage html
```

The key is the `-p` parameter which creates different logs for each procedure which at the end [get combined](http://coverage.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cmd.html#combining-data-files) with the `combine` command.

Following the [TDD with Python](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000000754/ch01.html) book, I run the selenium tests against the Django development server and the coverage result takes into account all the executed tests.